# Filtered view of collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

is there a filtered view of a collection (a subset of it) in Java, so that adding new item to it can also affect the source collection?

e.g.

```
List<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
source.add("a");
source.add("b");
List<String> view = source.stream().filter(i -> "b".equals(i)).collect(...);
view.add("c"); // source now contains also "c"
```

Comment: There is no built-in facility like this AFAIK.

Comment: Your `source` list doesn’t support adding elements to begin with. A view to that list can’t add this ability. Besides that, there would be a semantic problem. What should happen when you call `view.add(…)` with an element rejected by the filter? The contract of `List` requires `add` to always add the element but the contract of a filtered list requires the element not to appear in the list.

Comment: Thanks @Holger . Edited the code to allow adding to source. As for your second comment, the view is more a list initially created from filtering the source list, not a consistent filter applying on top of the source list. Hence adding to view is fine.

Comment: @Holger "*The contract of List requires add to always add the element*" It doesn't. The docs for `add` specifically lists "IllegalArgumentException - if some property of this element prevents it from being added to this list".

Comment: Can you  provide an elaborate description of the **use-cases** for the View (maybe accompanied by a `code/pseudocode`) to make it clear what do you want from the View. ***E.g. :*** element offered to the View  (can it be rejected if doesn't match the `Predicate` ?) / element was added to the Source  (should it be reflected in the View) / element was removed from the View / element was removed from the Source. So what are the use-cases and is the expected behavior for each of them for both the Source and the View?

Comment: @Holger Rejection is not a problem, as exceptions can be thrown (or just by adding nothing). In fact, Guava's `filter` in collection utilities does that and cooperates well with mutable lists (obviously `ArrayList` is one if them).

Comment: @Michael don’t you think that a policy of throwing an exception should be specified by the OP if intended?

Comment: @Holger Regardless of whether I was right to assume an exception might be acceptable, or you were right to assume it wasn't, you used the phrase "List requires", which is objectively wrong. It doesn't require it.

Comment: @WildernessRanger “just by adding nothing” would be a clear violation of `List`’s contract. There would be other problems as well, like what `add(index, element)` should do when translating the index to the unfiltered list is ambiguous. However, I can’t see a `List` returning method in Guava’s API you have linked anyway. It’s an entirely different thing if you only get a `Collection` as result.

Comment: @Michael the comment was referring to the non-exceptional case. Yes that’s an (over)simplification. But more importantly, it was intended to emphasize the need for clarification and now that [the OP has clarified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203490/filtered-view-of-collection-in-java?noredirect=1#comment131016358_74203490) the intention, which is *not* to throw an exception, we can stop nitpicking.

Comment: @Holger You're right. I had reminded such pracitce will violate the general contract in my answer. I just wanted to explain the possibility of rejection won't prevent implementation. Besides, it's true `filter` cannot return a list (I'll add it in my answer), but OP is only asking for collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK provides only index-based view of the list with the method [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

Thus, the changes to the view can be applied to the source list too if the "filter" is constructed using `List::indexOf` and/or `List::lastIndexOf`.

This should be enough for a limited case of having *a single range* matching the condition:

```java
List<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
source.add("a");
source.add("b");
source.add("b");

List<String> view = source.subList(source.indexOf("b"), source.lastIndexOf("b") + 1);

System.out.println("view: " + view);
view.add("c");

System.out.println("added view: " + view);
System.out.println("fixed src: " + source);
```

Output:

```
view: [b, b]
added view: [b, b, c]
fixed src: [a, b, b, c]
```

---

As for the *filtered view* of a list which stores all the source's elements matching some condition, such view would have to maintain a collection of sublists/subranges in general case and implement `List` interface appropriately.

The Guava [`Collections2.filter`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) mentioned by @Wilderness Ranger [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74206671/13279831) may be an example of the filtered view, however, its documentation states that its methods `add`/`addAll` would throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the predicate is not satisfied, so in your example an attempt to add "c" would fail for the predicate `"b"::equals`.

Comment: *"... above may be an example of the filtered view, however, its documentation states that its methods `add`/`addAll` would throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the predicate is not satisfied..."* Thanks for reminding. I have edited my answer to point it out, and provided a bypassing solution (though not recommended).

Answer (score 3):

Of course. You can create one by yourself by subclassing `AbstractCollection` (which implements most of the methods in `Collection` and you just need to write a few methods according to your needs). Then add the underlying collection as a member, override getters to apply the predicate to it and return the filtered results, override `add(E)` to put elements, and then it can basically work.
In fact, [Guava](https://guava.dev/) library has already provided [`Collections2.filter(Collection, Predicate)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection,com.google.common.base.Predicate)) (and also its set and map versions, but no list variant as indices become a problem when filtered) through which you can create a performant filtered view of any `Collection` by a predicate function easily, allowing additions if the underlying collection is mutable and *the predicate is satisfied*. <sub><sup>(Its mechanism is not complex, so you can also copy its implementation if not willing to include one more library ;)</sup></sub> Please note that, however, as `"c"` does not satisfy the predicate above, `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown in OP's example. But still, you can subclass `AbstractCollection` and pass everything else to the filtered view but add to the underlying collection directly. The only problem is this kind of "add" operation will not follow collection's general contract.

**Update:** However, there seems to be no way to construct a two-way view from `Stream` like OP's example, as operators do not know the sources of streams, and streams flow in one way.