# Can i iterate over specific Elements in a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, iterator

Given a list of Elements. For example list1 = {a,b,c,d,e}
I want to return an iterator that only iterates over the elements that satisfy a certain condition.

If for example b,d,e meet that condition, then the return value is an iterator that iterates only over those elements b,d,e.

Not allowed to use builtin java collections.
Also I have built my own linked list and iterator.

I have tried doing this by creating a list and adding only the elements where the condition is met.
Then returning an iterator over that new list.
The problem is, that later on i want to remove elements with this iterator and those removed elements should also be removed in the original list.

Is this somehow possible?

I am aware that this does not work:

```
public Iterator<Y> iterator(X x) {
        MyLinkedList<Y> temp = new MyLinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listY.size(); i++) {
            if(!x.satisfies(listY.get(i))){
                temp.addFirst(listY.get(i));
                listY.remove(i);
            }
        }
        MyIterator<Y> iter1 = new MyIterator<>(listY);
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            listY.addFirst(temp.get(i));
        }
        return iter1;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. please show us some code so we can help you

Comment: This already answered: [Remove objects from an ArrayList based on a given criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316629/remove-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-a-given-criteria)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove objects from an ArrayList based on a given criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316629/remove-objects-from-an-arraylist-based-on-a-given-criteria)

Comment: I have added some code. That is not quite what i want. I want to return an iterator that iterates over the certain elements of the list, but then also remove from that same list later on and not a copy.

Comment: Does it have to be an iterator or could you use a `.stream().filter(...)`?

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74203490/642706) but for adding rather than deleting element.

Comment: What if your list contains multiples, either the same object (identity) or similar objects (`equals`)?

Comment: Not allowed to use builtin java collections...
As you can see i have built my own linked list and iterator.
There are no identical elements in the list allowed.
The problem has more to do with the iterator than the removing itself.

Comment: So this is a school assignment? You should mention that in your Question, along with constraints.

Comment: You probably want to keep a reference to the "current" node and then every time find the "next node" (ignoring your specific elements). Same for "hasNext".